# Use RelativeSource as a ConverterParameter in a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I am trying to use a converter in an items control `ItemContainerStyle` to convert a property of an item in the `ItemsControl` to an X value. To do the conversion, I also need a reference to the parent `UserControl` that the `ItemsControl` is contained in. I tried to use `RelativeSource`, but in the `Convert` function, the parameter is not a `UserControl` but an instance of `RelativeSource`. Here's my XAML:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Path="StartTime" 
                             Converter="{StaticResource startTimeToXConverter}"
                             ConverterParameter="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax, or is there another way of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to bind the `Parameter` you should usually use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) instead.